# SWTBOT selecting text of a dialog

Tags: swtbot

i'm running a SWTBot test and i don't know how to select the text(message) of a dialog.

i can get the text of the shell like:

```
       bot.activeShell().getText().equals("Login error")
```

seen method for tooltip but not message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

shell.getText() would return the Shell title.
If you want the message inside the dialog, then you have to "find" it. You'll probably need to use "bot.label()" and similar methods.